# How to copy files inside a local virtual machine or how to edit a yml file inside a local virtual machine? (docker stack)

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I'm following a tutorial on docker stack, swarm, compose, etc.

the teacher connects to a VM of the swarm and then deploys a docker stack from this directory `docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1`:

```
docker stack deploy -c example-voting-app-stack.yml voteapp
```

However, I can't get there because I don't know how to copy the yaml compose file from the course repository to the directory inside the VM.

How can I find out where is `docker@node1` located in my PC ?

Here is what I tryed:

```
docker-machine start node1 

Docker-machine ssh node1
```

So I get

```
Tommaso@N552VW-Tommaso MINGW64 /c/Applicazioni_Tommaso/Docker Toolbox
$ Docker-machine ssh node1
   ( '>')
  /) TC (\   Core is distributed with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
 (/-_--_-\)           www.tinycorelinux.net
```

then

```
docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1$ pwd
/home/docker
```

ok then, but where is `/home/docker` located in my PC ?

So I tryed to get around the obstacle by creating a yml file inside the VM and then editing it, rather than copying it from another directory.

```
# create the directory
docker@node1:~$ mkdir srv
docker@node1:~$ cd srv
docker@node1:~/srv$ mkdir swarm-stack-1
docker@node1:~/srv$ cd swarm-stack-1
docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1$

# create the yml file
touch example-voting-app-stack.yml
```

and here I stop because I don't know how to edit the file.

I can nor install vim or install a program to install vim.

This is what I tryed:

```
docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1$ vim example-voting-app-stack.yml
-bash: vim: command not found

docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1$ apt-get vim
-bash: apt-get: command not found
docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1$ yum install vim
-bash: yum: command not found
docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1$ apk install vim
-bash: apk: command not found
docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1$ sudo apt-get install vim
sudo: apt-get: command not found

docker@node1:~/srv/swarm-stack-1$ nano
-bash: nano: command not found
```

So, can somebody help me to understand how to copy files inside my VM (so finding out what is its path in my PC) or how to install a program to install vim and then install vim inside my VM ?

Comment: Can't you ask those questions to "the teacher"?

Comment: I already did but I'm getting no answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The solution here is not to ssh into the VM, and instead to change to the VM context with:

```
docker-machine env node1
eval $(docker-machine env node1)
```

By doing so, you are in the VM context, so `docker node ls` and all the swarm commands work, but you still have access to your local files, because you're not in the VM.

So, after running the two lines above, I can finally switch my current directory to the course repo containing the docker-compose file I want to input in the docker stack deploy command, and run:

```
docker stack deploy -c example-voting-app-stack.yml voteapp
```

When you are done, to change the context back to the local machine do:

```
docker-machine env -u
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
```